# Regular expression to consider special characters in a string

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

The issue is I have to tokenize data into tokens based on spaces at the same time I can't tokenize the data based on special characters. Right now the regex I have is

```
       (\w*[-*#+=;:\/,~_ ]*\w+)
```

With this when I process the string

```
    1-CHECK ON BLOCKS BELOW IF MARKET CORRECTION ARE LOADED: PCORP:BLOCK=ANCTRLG&amp;V5PTCLG;   AF55722  BRTBMWA-3289 (AF55722) in block ANCTRLG (Product ID: CAAZ 107 4493 R1A10 )  AF55736  BRTBMWA-3290 (AF55726)in block V5PTCLG  (Product ID: CAAZ 107 4260 R2A08 )  IF MARKET CORRECTIONS ARE LOADED THEN V5 INTERFACE PROPERTY MUST BE DEFINED AS FOLLOW : MUXFIM : ACC-OFF (Accelerate Alligment is not active) WLL    : ACC-ON  (Accelerate Alligment is active ) :  EXAPC:V5ID=v5id,PROP=ACC-OFF;
```

What it does is tokenizes the string based on spaces at the same time it also tokenizes the data based on special character like

```
             :  EXAPC:V5ID=v5id is tokenized to :  EXAPC, :V5ID and =v5id rather want it to split as : and EXAPC:V5ID=v5id
```

I want to avoid this any idea on this any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use a paren around the range and `\w` but before the `+`

Comment: Why not just use .* for the whole thing as that will match any character you like to throw at it?

Comment: Move the `\w` inside the character class, `[-*#+=;:\/,~_ \w]+`

Comment: In your special case [**`[-\w\ ]+`**](https://regex101.com/r/diWaWJ/1) will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches "an optional word, then an optional list of special characters, then another word". In case you have two words, there is no option of having a special character before the first word.
What you're probably looking for is `([-*#+=;:\/,~_ \w]+)`.

Comment: I have tried the provided regex, but it does not fulfill my requirement. I have updated the requirement accordingly. Please have a look into it.

Comment: Simply remove the space, leaving you with `([-*#+=;:\/,~_\w]+)`.